# How to dynamically remove imageViews stacked up on one another

Tags: uiimageview, titanium-mobile

I have tried the following code, the task I am trying to do is to first populate the window with an image stack and then every time you click on one, it removes it one by one.

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'gray', 'black'];

    for (var i in colors) {

        var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            backgroundColor : colors[i],
            top : 50,
            left : 30,
            width : 200,
            height : 200
        });

        $.win.add(image);
    }

    image.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert(e);
        alert(JSON.stringify(e.source));
        $.win.remove(image);
    });
```

and then when they click on each image, it gets removed from the window - the next one is then shown.

The event listener works fine for the first image view, but then stops working with the underlying ones.

I know that this can easily be done with a scrollableView, but I would like to try and do this using an image View stack.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the event listener inside the loop !

```
   var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'gray', 'black'];
   for (var i in colors) {
      var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({ 
           backgroundColor : colors[i],
           top : 50, 
           left : 30,
           width : 200,
           height : 200
         }); 
    //this is what you should do 
    image.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
             alert(e); alert(JSON.stringify(e.source)); $.win.remove(image);
         });
    $.win.add(image); 
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: but i have answered his question.

Comment: You should [edit] the answer, rather than posting a comment. This would prevent others from flagging your answer as a comment.

Comment: How can I prevent the user from seeing the imageview beneath the other, when it is loading up?

Comment: if loading take a several time you have to show a loading screen. You can use this [widget](https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.loading)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'gray', 'black'];

function imageHandler(_imgObj,_win)
{
    _imgObj.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert(e);
        alert(JSON.stringify(e.source));
        _win.remove(image);
    });
}

for (var i in colors) {

    var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        backgroundColor : colors[i],
        top : 50,
        left : 30,
        width : 200,
        height : 200
    });
    imageHandler(image,$.win);
    $.win.add(image);
}
```

What this does is remove the handler separates the handler and gives you more control. Through each iteration in the for-loop, each image has it's own handler defined and this should work.